# Case Statement With Count Function

Tags: sql, oracle

How would one write a Case Statement with a count greater than one? The below is what I have so far: I'm receiving an invalid identifier.

```
Select *, CASE WHEN COUNT(X.id ) >1 THEN X 
  ELSE  isnull END AS testing 
 from TestTable
```

Comment: I replaced the `plsql` tag with `oracle` (and `sql`) because there is no sign in the question that a stored procedure is involved. Only plain SQL

Comment: Which identifier is invalid?  make it valid, then you can work through the rest of the problem (like adding the necessary group by for aggregation)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the education.

Comment: You're getting an invalid identifier because `X` appears to be a table alias inside your invocation of the COUNT function - `COUNT(X.id )` - but appears to be a column name in your THEN clause `THEN X`. Also, `isnull` is a function - you probably want to replace it with just `NULL`. There are likely to be other problems with this query once you resolve this issue, though.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what your data structure is and what you want the expected results to be? You do not have a `GROUP BY` clause, so it would count the records for the entire table.  Plus you can't mix aggregations and non-aggregations that aren't in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. I was able to work through my problem as I'm new to Oracle.

The correct statement would be:

```
Select *, CASE WHEN COUNT(X.id ) >1 THEN 'X' 
  ELSE '' END AS testing 
 from TestTable

Group by *
```

Answer (score 0):

COUNT itself is an aggregate function that you have to use with GROUP BY.
But you can also use it as an analytic function:

```
SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN COUNT(t.id) OVER(PARTITION BY ...) > 1 THEN 'X'
ELSE '' END AS testing
FROM TEST_TABLE
```